# Gradle build failing at the very start of my project

Tags: java, android

Gradle sync failed: The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe

To be straight, Gradle is failing to build my project at the very start of creating the project. It's not even showing any signs of gradle building. The window is not showing much details to decribe the error, but down it there is the caption "Gradle sync failed: The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe"

Anyone with a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run application with Android Studio please look at your gradle settings.

I suppose you need to change Gradle JVM to point to the actual JDK.
Go to the settings and then search "Gradle"

[image]

Comment: That worked, thanks very much. Also if you may have a solution to jitsi meet dependency help me, i have a problem description here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74814000/jitsi-dependency-not-working-in-2022-in-android-studio