# jitsi dependency not working in 2022 in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Could not find org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:7.0.1. Click the link just after the code below to see the screenshots of this error

I tried putting the dependency correctly in gradle.build files but I keep getting this error. I've been straggling with it for a week

Can someone help me how you are dealing with this problem in 2022
?

**Here is gradle.build at project level**

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases"
        }
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
    }
}
```

**Here is gradle.build at app level**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.0' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}  
  
  
**Here is gradle.build at app level**
  
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mlimivirtualmeeting"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'

    //scalable size unit (support for different screen sizes)
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'

    //RecyclerView
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1' //1.1.0

    //Material design
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0' //1.1.0
    //MultiDex
    //implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    //Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.9.0'

    //Swipe refresh layout
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'

    //Firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.1' //'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.4.1'

    //jitsi meet
    implementation ('org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:7.0.1') { transitive = true }


}
```

[This is the error being displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqSwT.png)

Comment: It could be helpful, if you add the code of your *gradle.build* file as well as a printout of the error message.

Comment: I've put the build.gradle files now, you can also click the link just below them to see the screenshot of the error

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of Android Studios, `allprojects{}` might not be found in `build.gradle`.
In that case, the repository goes into the `settings.gradle` file in the root of your project (Modify the code in `settings.gradle`):

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

After this in module `build.gradle` use dependency

```
implementation ('org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:6.2.2') { transitive = true }
```

Your application is good with jitsi SDK v6.2.2.

**Note:** Jitsi SDK v7.0.0 or v7.0.1 will not work simply this way! SDK versions 7.x seems to have an issue with gradle versions. To implement Jitsi  SDK v7.x check your gradle version first & make sure it is set to gradle v7.4.2.

How to fix Gradle Version for this project?

- Go to **IDE and Project Settings** > **Project Structure** >
  **Project**
- Set **Gradle Version** to **7.4.2**

Now sync the project with:

```
implementation ('org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:7.0.1') { transitive = true }
```

You are all set with the latest version of Jitsi SDK as of 20/12/2022.

Good Luck!

Comment: getting this error Failed to resolve: org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:7.0.1. i have made above changes , but still getting same error.